# Inserting data to a table which isn't present in another table

Tags: mysql

I am having the below portion of the database to deal with. I am making an attendance system. I have to insert the record of students who haven't marked their attendance. If a student marks his/her attendance, their record will be saved in Attendance with status as **1**.
I've to make sure that when a button is pressed at the end, the students who are in Registered_Course table against a specific **teacher_id** from **Teacher** table, **batch_id** from the **Batch** table, and **course_id** from **Course** table, they should be marked as absent in the Attendance table by inserting their record.
I've tried using **Left Join** to get the **reg_number** from **Registered_Course** but it doesn't select the expected values. Maybe I am doing something wrong there.
here is my query without join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(reg_number) from Registered_Course R, Attendance A
where
R.id!=A.registered_course_id
and R.teacher_id=1 AND R.course_id='CSC112'
```

I am unable to get how should I deal with this. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: *I have to insert the record of students who haven't marked their attendance.* Why? Simple `SELECT students.student_ID, attendance.Date, attendance.student_ID IS NOT NULL AS attendance_mark FROM students LEFT JOIN attendance USING (student_ID) ...`

Comment: Images are frowned up here for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - please replace your image with table definitions in formatted text!

Comment: @Akina thanks for the idea. Would you please explain the query a bit more. In fact, I've to give teacher a choice to mark the absent students present if there are some issues on the student side. Therefore I was trying to do so. I've got your point. I'll deal with that but please explain your query a bit, if possible. Thanks